# Headless browser for multithreads application

Tags: .net, browser, automation, web-scraping, headless

I'm looking for a headless browser for .NET multithread application. It must has next features:

- Working **without any server installation**. I need just simple library
  to distribute with my application.
- **Ajax/HTML 5 support**. Ability to work with pages elements: find and read attributes through
  internal/external (SGMLReader) XML, or using API to click buttons,
  fill forms, etc.
- Correctly cookies container (correctly working with **multiple cookies response** and storing cookies during all session)
- **Customizable browser line** (even selecting Chrome/Firefox is enough)
- **Multithread**. So no static cookies container or smth. else. I need be
  able to login and working with same site under 2-100000 different
  users.
- **Fast working**
- **Working with https** by using insecure SSL.

I found this solutions:

- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). I don't understand how to work with this library from .NET, and if this solution suitable to my demands.
- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) with [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/). Not work with YUI library.
- [WebKit.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/).
- [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)
- [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)

but don't know what is a best. Will be pleasure if you suggest me best solution and give some .NET examples of using it.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761511/headless-webkit-wrapper-driver-no-install-for-net), and many others answers and I haven't found answer still.

Comment: This is a good question regarding tools.  No idea why you all are trying to close it.

Comment: Because the question is subjective and open to opinions.

Comment: How it can be subjective? Is there are more than one answer? I asked what library fully correspond to my demands. You can answer: Library1 is correspond. Or Library1 and Library2. But if you answered Library1, but Library1 is not correspond to one of demands it is not a correct answer. It's not an another point of view or subjective view. It's just an error answer.

Comment: That's why it's a vote.  This question is definitely in a grey area.

Comment: Just open [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and read what mean under [subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). And then you will understand that this question is NOT a subjective. If you read FAQ carefully you will see, that this Q is software tools and specific problem related. Thank you.

Comment: And if this area is grey for you, it's not mean, that this area is grey for all. I think there are many developers that solved this problem many times, so I just need their answers.

Comment: "but don't know what is a best." If you hadnt added that line, it would not have been closed. Shame, because this is a good question